# Can you identify this fragrant shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

It is European zone 8a, mid-May. The flowers have strong honey-like fragrance. The plant may be a climber or semi-climber since it grew around fence.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a beautiful specimen of [common privet (Ligustrum vulgare)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligustrum_vulgare). The lanceolate dark glossy leaves, the intense scent and especially the *four* petals are quite distinctive.

Comment: If Mr. Adams [is to be believed](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/806042-never-throw-the-letter-q-into-a-privet-bush), you should avoid heated Scrabble games in the vicinity of such bushes.